# Why is it very slow to record video from OpenGL windows?

Tags: opengl, windows-xp, directx

I tried to record video from my own OpenGL program window with FRAPS, but i get 7fps! Then i wrote the exact same program with DirectX and i get smooth 30fps. In both programs the rendering speed is 60 fps and CPU usage same. Resolution didnt seem to affect at all.

What could be the reason for this and how to make it as fast with OpenGL ?

**Edit:** I tested with empty scene, with only glClear() function used, and i still get only 7fps!

**Edit2:** My example program with minimized code size that causes this same low FPS issue: http://pastebin.com/8nGTsBX5 (code is from my another question, if you dont mind). Edit3: I also noticed that i can get higher FPS only with window size 320x240 (24fps only, though) or smaller.

Comment: If you're using immediate mode, then rewrite your program to use modern core profile and minimise GL calls inside the rendering loop.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus, could that really be a reason? sounds weird to me. But i think i will try that just to be sure. I also tried with my other GL program which uses very few GL calls, and it also got 7fps...

Comment: Immediate mode is widely known to be slow and obsolete. Even if it's not related to the issue at hand, you should not use it.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus, edit: i tested with empty scene, no drawing used at all, same issue: 7fps.

Comment: Then show us how you do your drawing in OpenGL. Without knowing that, there is not much to suggest.

Comment: @Bart, here is the program: http://pastebin.com/8nGTsBX5 (minimized code from another question), i tested that too, with and without triangle rendering: same low FPS.

Comment: Do you have properly installed graphics drivers? OpenGL performance is abysmal if you use only those drivers provided by Windows Update.

Comment: I can't reproduce what you're seeing. Even the debug build in high-res easily bumps into 60fps (based on the Fraps fps counter).

Comment: @datenwolf, im not sure about my drivers indeed. that might be the problem. my rule of thumb has always been: dont update if its not broken. i guess i have to update now, but im not happy doing that since i can almost know something else breaks then...

Comment: @datenwolf, post it as an answer and i can accept it; driver update fixed the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have properly installed graphics drivers? OpenGL performance is abysmal if you use only those drivers provided by Windows Update.

Comment: updating my drivers to latest version fixed this!